# Error 404 luego de crear un servidor Tomcat en Eclipse

Tags: tomcat

Tengo un problema con el servidor de Apache Tomcat versión 7.0.73. He creado un servidor de Tomcat en Eclipse versión neon 2, arranca sin problemas, y puedo acceder a la dirección de http://localhost:8080/.

El problema es que no me muestra el proyecto, me aparece un error 404. Me gustaría saber si alguien me podría dar una solución, tengo un Mac con sistema operativo El capitán.

---

**Editado luego de algunas pruebas:**

Pude solucionar el problema instalando otra versión de Tomcat (versión 7.0.75) y ya puedo arrancar cualquier proyecto. Pero tras instalar el Spring versión 3.8.3, me vuelve aparecer el error 404 al arrancarlo, y lo curioso es que sólo me pasa con un proyecto de Spring.

¿Se debe al mismo problema como explica mapusoft? ¿Qué cambios puedo realizar para que me funcione?

Comment: Creo recordar que cuando usabas Tomcat con Eclipse la pagina de inicio del propio Tomcat no estaba disponible.

Comment: Si queires acceder a tu landing page no tendria que ser http://localhost:8080/MiProyecto ?. Podrias cambair el puerto del tomcat en vez de 8080 al 8090 por ejemplo si te pasa lo mismo

Comment: Copia tu web.xml

Comment: AngelFG: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español y gracias por volver para compartir cómo has solucionado el problema. Las respuestas se deben publicar como respuesta y para promover esto, las políticas del sitio permiten que recibas puntos de reputación por los votos positivos de los demás miembros del sitio te den. Por favor anímate a hacerlo.

Comment: Referencia: [¿Puedo responder mi propia pregunta?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)